# Deployment of maven, spring application on jboss eap 7

Tags: hibernate, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jboss

when I am running my project in eclipse it's running perfectly fine but when I am creating a war of my project and deploying on jBoss EAP 7.0 it's giving Error like below and also doesn't create directories like tomcat creates, I have used **maven 4.0,** spring integration, **spring MVC and Hibernate**, properties of hibernate are stored in another file named application.properties. What might be the issue ? whats the correct procedure of deploying war on jboss am i missing anything ? ZealWay is my project.

```
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.CatchTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ChooseTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.OtherwiseTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.RemoveTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.ForEachTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.IfTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.SetTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.WhenTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.ForEachTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.ForTokensTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.IfTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.ImportTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.OutTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.ParamTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.RedirectTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.SetTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.UrlTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.WhenTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.BundleTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.FormatDateTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.FormatNumberTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.MessageTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.ParamTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.ParseDateTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.ParseNumberTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.RequestEncodingTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.SetBundleTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.SetLocaleTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.SetTimeZoneTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.TimeZoneTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.DateParamTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.ParamTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.QueryTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.SetDataSourceTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.TransactionTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.UpdateTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.xml.ExprTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.xml.ParamTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.xml.ParseTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.xml.TransformTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ForEachTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ForTokensTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ImportTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.OutTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ParamTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.RedirectTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.SetTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.UrlTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.WhenTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.BundleTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.FormatDateTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.FormatNumberTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.MessageTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.ParamTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.ParseDateTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.ParseNumberTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.RequestEncodingTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.SetBundleTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.SetLocaleTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.SetTimeZoneTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.TimeZoneTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.sql.DateParamTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.sql.ParamTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.sql.QueryTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.sql.SetDataSourceTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.sql.TransactionTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.sql.UpdateTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.xml.ExprTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.xml.ParamTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.xml.ParseTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.xml.TransformTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlFmtTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlSqlTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlXmlTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.ArgumentTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.BindErrorsTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.BindTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.EscapeBodyTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.EvalTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.HtmlEscapeTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.NestedPathTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.ParamTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.ThemeTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.TransformTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.UrlTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."ZealWay.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-ip</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.int.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-event</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.int.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.validation.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.el.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
            <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${c3P0.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>mchange-commons-java</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
            <version>${ehcache.version}</version>
        </dependency>           
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>               
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>src/target</warSourceDirectory>
                    <warName>ZealWay</warName>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>ZealWay</finalName>
    </build>
```

Comment: And you show no pom, no dependencies, no application code. Only an exception... generally you aren't creating the war in the way you should be creating it.

Comment: check if below is present in dependency <dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>

Comment: I have added this dependency but getting the same error..!

Answer (score 1):

The number one cause of this problem is Java EE API/implementation pollution in the built WAR file.

I've made the following changes to your dependencies which should improve matters:

1. Replaced all the `javax.*` dependencies with the all encompassing
   `javaee-api`. It is at `provided` scope because all these classes
   are provided by your server at runtime and you only need it to
   support compilation.
2. Added two `bom` style dependencies in a `dependencyManagement`
   fragment which defines appropriate `compile`, `runtime` and `provided` dependency versions for your hibernate and spring components.
3. Upgraded your `log4j` dependency to a version which does not have the pom bug requiring you to add those exclusions.

Pundits will know that the `wildfly-javaee7-with-tools` includes the same Java EE 7 APIs (in a myriad of jars) as that defined by the additional `javaee-api` that I've added. This has been done for simplicity.

I also recommend that you remove the `maven-eclipse-plugin` definition because it has been retired and will usually will break the integration with the built in maven integration in modern Eclipse versions.

```
<properties>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.7.22</org.slf4j-version>
    <c3P0.version>0.9.5.2</c3P0.version>
    <ehcache.version>2.6.11</ehcache.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-javaee7-with-tools</artifactId>
            <version>10.1.1.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-ip</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-event</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>javax.batch-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.batch</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
        <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.xml.stream</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>${c3P0.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>mchange-commons-java</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        <version>${ehcache.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.38</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```